# How do I get the the closest form data using jQuery when a child input has changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple forms in a page that contains a number of input checkboxes, when one of the form inputs change I want to collect all the parent forms data into a JSON array so I can post this somewhere.

I am struggling to get the post data into an array, I was planning to use `this.closest("form").serializeObject()` but this doesn't appear to work.

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.closest(...).serializeObject is not a
> function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("jquery ready!");

  $('form input:checkbox').change(function() {
    var jsonArray;
    var formData = this.closest("form").serializeObject();
    console.log(formData);

  });

});
```

```html
<form action="http://myurl.com/1" id="form-1">
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="monday" value="1" id=""> Monday</label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday" value="1" id=""> Tuesday</label>

</form>
<form action="http://myurl.com/2" id="form-2">
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="monday" value="1" id=""> Monday</label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday" value="1" id=""> Tuesday</label>

</form>
<form action="http://myurl.com/3" id="form-3">
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="monday" value="1" id=""> Monday</label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday" value="1" id=""> Tuesday</label>
</form>
```

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/sfdxnotfound/pen/pogOgoj?editors=1111)

Comment: Try `$(this).closest("form").serialize()`

Comment: This almost does it, how can I convert this into a JSON object instead of a string?

Comment: try this `$(this).closest("form").serializeArray()`

Comment: You need to include the jquery-serialize-object plugin to make it work for `serializeObject()`

Comment: @turivishal Please turn this into the answer. This is what I needed thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var formObj = {};
   $('form input:checkbox').change(function() {     
        let form = $(this).closest("form");
        formObj[form.attr('id')] = {};
        form.serializeArray().forEach(function(elem){
            formObj[form.attr('id')][elem.name] = elem.value;
        });
        console.log(formObj);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="http://myurl.com/1" id="form-1">
    <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="monday" value="1" id=""> Monday</label>
    <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday" value="1" id=""> Tuesday</label>
</form>
<form action="http://myurl.com/2" id="form-2">
    <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="monday" value="1" id=""> Monday</label>
    <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday" value="1" id=""> Tuesday</label>
</form>
<form action="http://myurl.com/3" id="form-3">
    <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="monday" value="1" id=""> Monday</label>
    <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday" value="1" id=""> Tuesday</label>    
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're using normal vanilla javascript `this`. Since you're using JQuery, you should use `$(this)`

> By using `$(this)`, you enabled jQuery functionality for the object.
> By just using `this`, it only has generic Javascript functionality. i.e. you need $(this) for jQuery functions, but when you want to access basic javascript methods of the element that don't use jQuery, you can just use this.

So inside your function, your `formData` variable to

```
var formData = $(this).closest("form").serializeObject();
```

To keep things simple and clear, I will be using your example in the example below or click on the codepen link below.

To get the data in an array you can use `.serializeArray();` or use `.serializeObject();`to get the data a key-value pair object depending on your choice and intention;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("jquery ready!");

  $("form input:checkbox").change(function() {
    var jsonArray;
    var formData = $(this).closest("form").serializeObject();
    console.log(formData);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="http://myurl.com/1" id="form-1">
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="monday" value="1" id=""> Monday</label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday" value="1" id=""> Tuesday</label>
</form>

<form action="http://myurl.com/2" id="form-2">
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="monday" value="1" id=""> Monday</label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday" value="1" id=""> Tuesday</label>
</form>

<form action="http://myurl.com/3" id="form-3">
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="monday" value="1" id=""> Monday</label>
  <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday" value="1" id=""> Tuesday</label>
</form>
```

[CodePen Link Here](https://codepen.io/the_olusolar/pen/JjGaGqe?editors=1011)